# VSCode Azure Functions - Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm unable to upload the code to azure functions for some reason. It was working few days ago when I tried.

Now I get the below error. Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

```
4:27:59 PM: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')
4:28:03 PM: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')
4:31:28 PM: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')
```

Only thing I modified this time is the `local.settings.json` as below.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "##########",
    "CosmosDBConnection": "##########",
    "StorageConnectionString": "#########"
  }
}
```

tried the old version of the code which used to work and there were no modification but now that also reports the same error.

Any idea what the issue is? I'm guessing something wrong with vscode.

Here is my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "#############",
    "CosmosDBConnection": "#############",
    "StorageConnectionString": "#############"
  }
}
```

Here is the .vscode\settings.json

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "C#",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "publish (functions)"
}
```

Update: Uploading from resource view works but uploading from workspace doesn't work. Here is a [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues/2304#issuecomment-1213829518) to the bug reported and the work around.

Comment: Could you please try including "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "projectname" in settings.json file of the Azure Functions Project!

Comment: No it doesn't help. Updated the question with the local.settings.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out.

Delete or move the `.vscode` folder from the project folder and restart the Visual studio code and it'll initialize the function app again. Now you can upload the function without any issues.

Comment: that didn't work for me

Comment: Did the VScode initialize the function app after you deleted the folder and restarted the client?

Comment: Doesn't work for me too :(

Comment: This doesn't solve for me.

Comment: not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

You can set *Group by Resource Type*:
[image]

Source on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureresourcegroups/issues/608).